# Remember name and email in comment box wordpress

Tags: php, android, wordpress, comments

i made ios and Android app with WebView of my Wordpress website.
i have added comment box in index file mean comment box after every post so users can comment without going to single post file. now i want that if someone commented on post , next time comment box should remember their name and email so they shouldn't write name and email again and again
is that possible ?

this is my WebView Url

```
http://m.wahstatus.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save the required information as a cookie in the user's pc and when they login again, it will be fetched if they have used it previously.

There are many other possible ways but with the information that you have provided, I think this will be most appropriate one to do.

Comment: users cant sign up for my website, i have disabled that option

Comment: That is why I've mentioned about cookies.
Go through these links to learn how helpful it will be for you.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/cookies-information-websites-store-on-your-computer

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import